# Correlation coefficient of normal random random variables

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be jointly normal with mean zero. Show that the correlation coefficient equals $\cos(\pi P\{XY<0\})$. This is a problem in Loeve's book. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: $(X,Y)$ is an explicit linear transform of $(U,V)$ standard normal and the distribution of $(U,V)$ is invariant by the rotations.

Comment: What I am unable to see is how cos((pi)P{XY<0}) can be computed explicitly in terms of EXY.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $U = X/ \sigma_X$ and $V = Y/\sigma_Y$.

Then

$$P\{XY < 0 \} = P\{UV < 0\} \\ = \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_0^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-u^2+ 2\rho uv - v^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right)\,du \, dv \\ + \frac{1}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{- \infty}^0 \exp\left(\frac{-u^2+ 2\rho uv - v^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right)\,du \, dv \\ = \frac{2}{2 \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^0\int_0^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-u^2+ 2\rho uv - v^2}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right)\,du \, dv \\ =\frac{1}{ \pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{\pi/2}^\pi\int_0^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-r^2(1 - \sin 2 \theta)}{2(1-\rho^2)} \right)r\,dr \, d\theta $$

Comment: What I am unable to see is how cos((pi)P{XY<0}) can be computed explicitly in terms of EXY.

Comment: If you computed the last double integral (after the switch to polar coordinates) you should get $\arccos (\rho) / \pi$.  First integrate over r.  That part is easy.